# How do I turn off highlighting for $...$ in tex-mode

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I like to use highlighting when working with emacs.  But I don't like some of the default settings.  I recently installed emacs 24.4 on my iMac.  I really don't like all the highlighting of math expressions such as

```
$5$
```

I used to do something like

```
(fset 'tex-font-lock-syntactice-face-function 'ignore)
```

or

```
(fset 'tex-math-face 'ignore)
```

but that no longer works.

How can I disable highlight for math expressions but keep most everything else?

Comment: I use a custom version of `tex-mode.el` and I commented out `(,(concat "\\$\\$?\\(?:[^$\\{}]\\|\\\\.\\|{" (funcall inbraces-re (concat "{" (funcall inbraces-re "{[^}]*}") "*}")) "*}\\)+\\$?\\$") (0 tex-math-face))` in my own personal custom version because I don't use math.  If you don't want to comment out the source, then you might be interested in coping the current setting of `tex-font-lock-keywords-1`, and commenting out that section and setting the new portion -- e.g., `(setq tex-font-lock-keywords-1 [EVERYTHING EXCEPT WHAT SHOULD BE STRICKEN])`  If you are using AUCTeX, I don't know.

Comment: It is lines 503 to 507 in the public release of Emacs 24 within `tex-mode.el`  Most people treat the source code as sacred and use things like `(setq . . . ` instead of touching the source.  I like to create my own libraries for things I use every day (like writing documents for business, etc.), starting by copying the source code, and then I modify the daylights out of the source.

Comment: Are you using AUCTeX or the basic tex-mode? (To see that: press `C-h m` and see whether the mode is defined in `tex-site` (AUCTeX) or `tex-mode` (basic).) Do you want to turn off highlighting just for `$…$` or for everything such as math environments?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the highlighting using `set-face-foreground` (or more generally `set-face-attribute`.  `$..$` seems to be highlighted with `font-latex-math-face`, so to set the foreground to whatever the default is we can use `(set-face-foreground 'font-latex-math-face nil)`.  It's still "highlighted" but it will look identical to the surrounding text.

Answer (score 1):

In the following I assume that you are using auctex.

Remove the syntax descriptor for `?$`  from `font-latex-syntax-alist` after loading "font-latex" to avoid fontification of inline formulas delimited by `$`.

```
(eval-when '(compile)
  (require 'cl))

(eval-after-load "font-latex"
  '(setq font-latex-syntax-alist (cl-delete-if (lambda (pair) (eq (car pair) ?$)) font-latex-syntax-alist)))
```